# My project keeps logging me out, Why is this happening? (CLOSED)

Tags: python

I'm writing a code that will allow me to save my data into the database. But for some reason, whenever I type in a response, it refers to the else statement and logs me out.

Here's my code:

```
username = "storagei"
password = "something"

# asking for a username and password.
userInput = input("welcome back to safespace! Please type in your username to access your data.\n")


if userInput == username:
    userInput = input("Password?\n")   
    if userInput == password:
       print("Welcome back to safespace Izzy!")
        
    else:
       print("That is the wrong password. Please try again.")
       exit(1)
else:
    print("There is no username that matches what your responce. Please try again.")
    exit(2)

print "You can open_storage, add_to_storage, or log_out"   
userInput = input("What would you like to do?\n")

log_out = "Thanks for using safespace. Come back soon!"
open_storage = "opening files."
add_to_storage = "what do you like to add?"

if userInput == log_out:
   print("Thanks for using safespace. Come back soon!")
   exit(3)
   if userInput == open_storage:
      print("opening storage. Please wait...")
   if userInput == add_to_storage:
      print("what would you like to add?")
else:
    print("not a valid input. Logging you out.")
```

So for some reason, when it gets to this part of the code:

```
print "You can open_storage, add_to_storage, or log_out"   
userInput = input("What would you like to do?\n")

log_out = "Thanks for using safespace. Come back soon!"
open_storage = "opening files."
add_to_storage = "what do you like to add?"

if userInput == log_out:
   print("Thanks for using safespace. Come back soon!")
   exit(3)
   if userInput == open_storage:
      print("opening storage. Please wait...")
   if userInput == add_to_storage:
      print("what would you like to add?")
else:
    print("not a valid input. Logging you out.")
```

I have fixed my code on my own. Here is the working script I have with all the edits if you would like to see them.

```
username = "storagei"
password = "something"

# asking for a username and password.
userInput = input("welcome back to safespace! Please type in your username to access your data.\n")


if userInput == username:
    userInput = input("Password?\n")   
    if userInput == password:
       print("Welcome back to safespace Izzy!")
        
    else:
       print("That is the wrong password. Please try again.")
       exit(1)
else:
    print("There is no username that matches what your responce. Please try again.")
    exit(2)

print "You can open_storage type in o. add_to_storage type in a. log_out type in l. delete_files type in d. or edit_files type in e."   
userInput = input("What would you like to do?\n")

l = "l"
o = "o"
a = "a"
d = "d"
e = "e"

if userInput == l:
   print("Thanks for using safespace. Come back soon!")
   exit(3)
if userInput == o:
      print("opening storage. Please wait...")
if userInput == a:
      print("what would you like to add?")
if userInput == d:
      print("what file do you want to delete?")
if userInput == e:
      print("what file do you want to edit?")
    
else:
  if userInput != l:
    if userInput != o:
      if userInput != a:
        if userInput != d:
          if userInput != e:
             print("not a valid input. Logging you out.")
```

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. The `open_storage` and `add_to_storage` cases are after the `exit` _inside_ the `userInput == log_out` branch, where they can never be reached.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if userInput == 'open_storage':
   print("opening storage. Please wait...")
elif userInput == 'add_to_storage':
   print("what would you like to add?")
elif userInput == 'log_out':
   print("Thanks for using safespace. Come back soon!")
   exit(3)
else:
   print("not a valid input. Logging you out.")
```

Comment: I found another way to solve my problem. But thanks for the suggestion.